# Example for GROUP BY restriction

Tags: sql

In the postgreSQL documentation, it says:

> When GROUP BY is present, it is not valid for the SELECT list expressions to refer to ungrouped columns except within aggregate functions or if the ungrouped column is functionally dependent on the grouped columns, since there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column

I don't understand the part about "`there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column`".

Can someone please give me an example of this? How can there be more then one possible value to return for an ungroup column?

Comment: I'm asking for an example/explanation of the documanetation, not a solution to a specific problem

Comment: I rephrased my question. As I said, it's about the documentation only. I'm just trying to understand it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider this table:

```
col_1 | col_2 | col_3
A       10      10
A       11      20
B       20      40
C       40      60
```

And try running this query that sums over the values of col_3

```
SELECT col_1, col_2, SUM(col_3)
FROM   t1
GROUP BY col_1
```

The above query can have 2 possible outputs:

```
Output 1: Here, col_2 = 10
---------------------------
col_1   |   col_2   |   SUM(col_3)
A           10          30      
B           20          40
C           40          60

Output 2: Here, col_2 = 11
---------------------------
col_1   |   col_2   |   SUM(col_3)
A           11          30 
B           20          40
C           40          60
```

And this is because col_2 was not included in the GROUP BY clause. Summation over col_3 happens as expected based on the grouping by col_1 but now the SQL engine does not know whether you wanted the row with A having col_2 as 11 or as 11. And hence, "there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column"

The above query will work fine with MySQL, it will randomly return one of the above 2 outputs whereas Oracle/SQL Server will throw the error that you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

> there would otherwise be more than one possible value to return for an ungrouped column

Let me try to explain this with a small sample of data:

```
CREATE TABLE yourtable ([year] int, [amt] int);

INSERT INTO yourtable ([year], [amt])
VALUES
  (2012, 50),
  (2012, 60),
  (2011, 100),
  (2011, 89),
  (2013, 25);
```

This sample has 3 separate years and now we want to get a sum of the amount for each year.

If you use the query:

```
select year, sum(amt) TotalPerYear
from yourtable
```

And you provide no `GROUP BY` of the `Year` column, then how will the database engine know what value to select for the year because there is more than one value in the column.

The `GROUP BY` is saying I want the sum for each year, it is not saying I want the sum for whatever year it decides.

```
select year, sum(amt) TotalPerYear
from yourtable
group by year
```

The `GROUP BY` every column in the select, ensures that you are getting the correct aggregation for the grouped columns.

MySQL is a database that allows this behavior and it [explicitly states in the docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) that including columns in a select list that are not in a group by or aggregate function, can lead to unexpected results.

From the MySQL Docs:

> You can use this feature to get better performance by avoiding unnecessary column sorting and grouping. *However, this is useful primarily when all values in each nonaggregated column not named in the GROUP BY are the same for each group. The server is **free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate.*** Furthermore, the selection of values from each group cannot be influenced by adding an ORDER BY clause. Sorting of the result set occurs after values have been chosen, and ORDER BY does not affect which values the server chooses.

Comment: can we do select * in such case?

Answer (score 0):

Let's say you have a table of people... Name, city, phone number. And you want to get a count of people by city. So you select city and count of * and group by city. It would not make sense to include phone number in your query (ungrouped) because there would most likely be more than one phone number for each grouping and the db would not know what you want.